# How to work declare a localstorage proxy with inline store in the List?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

**BackGround** : I am working with a List and store config of list. I am making an Ajax call everytime and display the data in the list.
Now, i want to use the localstorage proxy with this.

Here is my code,

```
    xtype : 'list',
    id : 'namesList',
    store : {
    id : 'namesStore',
    autoLoad : true,
     fields : ['text', 'value'],
        proxy : {
            type:'ajax',
            url : 'dataFolder/namesList.json',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'record'
            }
            },
            },
        itemTpl :'<div class = mainContent>{text}</div>',
```

My issue is "How can I use localstorageProxy in this configuration. 
When I directly add

```
proxy : {
    type : 'localstorage',
    id: 'namesListLocalStorage',
    url : 'dataFolder/nameList.json',
    }
```

It does not display any records. Any pointers will help a lot.

Thank you

Comment: The easiest might be to catch the jamesList.json with an Ajax call and add the data to the localStorage Store and sync the data. The other way would be to have two stores and switch stores for the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the below mechanism.

I have declared a remote store to get the date from the server and a local store to sync with the remote store and store the data to the local storage.

My controller always checks if there are no records in the localstore then only the remote store will call the server and fetch the data.

Once the sync of local store to remotestore is completed, I explictly store localstore as the store for the list using list.setStore method.

Thanks